# How to determine the key, divide the tabs and count the pauses when writing the sheet music of a song? (image included)

Tags: piano, scales, sheet-music, key-signatures

Below is my first attempt to write the sheet music for the song "My Way" by Sinatra:

[image]

Then I googled and compared with what I found in the internet, for example this one:

[image]

So my questions are:

1. Why does it start the first tab at the second note? How was I suppose to know that? Is that usually the case?
2. I was confused because although I wanted to assume the time signature was 4/4, my first tab had only 3 beats. Later I realized that there is a pause adding up to 4 beats. How can I "hear the pause" to write the sheet music?
3. How to determine the key and the scale of this song? So that I can know whether that first C sharp in the first line is an accidental or just part of the scale?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The first note is a pick-up note, where, to complete the 4  beats, the rest of the notes are located at the "way." part of the song at the end of the same stanza.
2. You beat the drum at the start of every measure. I believe the half note in the 1st 2 measures should be a dotted note.
3. The key signature is the key to determining the key. Since there are no flats and sharps, this song is to be played in the key of C

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it's not tab, it's music written on staves. Tab is mostly, these days, for guitar, and has 6 lines!

1. The music has a note before the barline, because the 'And' is an anacrucis, which is like a pickup word, putting the 'now' firmly on the main beat - the first beat of the bar.You get to know that, by listening to the emphasis that's given to words (and/or notes) in a song.
2. Don't 'hear the pause'. Instead, tap to the general rhythm and feel where the kick drum might be heard. That's usually the first beat of a bar. Then count till the next main beat. In this case, you'll get to 4 before you have to start at 1 again.
3. The key signature will give a clue as to key. If there's an accidental, it'll be written as such - as a note NOT in the key signature. All this, assuming you see the music. If not, then the key is more often than not reflected in the last note/chord of the song. The chord that makes you feel as though the song could and indeed does come to rest and finish there, without a feeling that something else will have to follow.